# Multiple Content Types Duplicating Values in Calculated Column when updating CT

Tags: content-type, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, multiple-values

**List Setup**

I have a list setup with 3 content types. 
Content Type A, Content Type B, Content Type C

The list has 3 choice columns setup for each content type. This enables the choices available to users in the column to be tailored to the content type selected.

The choice columns as follows; Location (A), Location (B), Location (C).

A calculated column combines the three location columns (A+B+C)

**The Issue**

When editing a list item sometimes the content type can change. The user changes the content type and then sets the new location.

SharePoint stores the value set within 'Location' from both the current content type and the previous content type. This means that the calculated column returns two values.

Is there anyway that this can be avoided and SharePoint only return 'Location' from the content type?, or somehow clear 'Location' from the previous content type?

I have tried to include [Content Type] within the calculated column for however column can not be used. 
Also tried to include hidden fields to identify the content type however we have the same issue.